# Azure Rest API - Get all vms from resource ordered

Tags: rest, azure, virtual-machine, azure-monitoring

I am trying to make a simple ranking (like a top 10) of the vms that I have in a specific resource. For example the top 10 vms in percentage cpu metric. Right now what I am doing is to collect the metrics of each one individually and then comparing them with the others. I couldn't find anything in the api that would make this less rudimentary, do you know any query or filter that approximates of what I am requesting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today the REST API for metrics can't do any aggregation across multiple resources.